# Rstudio起動時に前回エラーを起こした作業スペースが読み込まれて作業ができない

Tags: r, rstudio

RStudioでコードを書いていたところ、以下のエラーが表示され、その後スクリプトに書き込みはできるもの計算ができなくなりました。

```
fatal error; unexpected exception: string too long
```

ファイルを消去すれば解決するだろうと思い、エラーが出たファイルを削除してRStudioを再び起動すると、エラーが出た作業スペースが読み込まれて先程と同様の状況になりました。

Rstudioを複数開くと、新たに起動したRStudioが正常に動作したのでそのデータで簡単な計算を行いデータを保存し、保存したデータを開くとまたエラーを起こした作業スペースが読み込まれ、作業ができなくなりました。

以下を試しましたが解決しませんでした。

- 拡張子が `.R`, `.Rhistory` のファイルを削除
- RおよびRStudioのアンインストール、再インストール

浅学な質問で大変恐縮ですが、どのようにすればRStudioが正常に使用できるようになりますか？

Comment: @taiyodayo　解決しました。本当にありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

RStudio社の公式ガイドに従って、RStudioをリセットしてみてください：
https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/200534577-Resetting-RStudio-Desktop-s-State